# Changing GD:SE logo for the day?

Tags: discussion, status-declined

I just noticed StackOverflows logo was changed as of recent events. Just wondering if we would like to do the same for a day or so. Not sure how we would go about changing the logo or how long it would take.

[image: changed logo]

A link to the SVG code: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhkgee7n/

Comment: I'm looking into if this is even feasible. I imagine its easier for StackOverflow then for all of us smaller off-shoots but I'll ask and find out.

Comment: I'm looking into it, but it's only viable if a bunch of people really want it - so I stuck [featured] on here to draw some attention.

Comment: Yeah sure, let's do it!

Comment: Does upvoting count as a vote for going ahead with this? :-)

Comment: Do keep in mind the possible backlash of users that disagree with either the intention (adding "politics" to SO sites) or the meaning (against the issue it represents). Some go even so far as [writing a greasemonkey script to remove it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297978/2564301).

Comment: @Jongware why not make that an answer?

Comment: @Darth_Vader: I dare not recommend yes or no. Some of the stronger reactions over at Meta-SO were pretty ... intimidating. Somehow such a simple gesture is highly polarizing.

Comment: @Jongware Personally I'd say intimidating reactions are a reason to DO something, to show that in a fair society intimidation isn't a way to get your way.

Comment: That said, I kinda feel like 3 days on, we might have already missed the boat on this one...

Comment: Even though I feel this is an issue we never should stop celebrating, I do agree with user#'s 'too late' statement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for suggesting this, and creating that cool new version of the icon.

I [mentioned above](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2681/changing-gdse-logo-for-the-day#comment5581_2681) that broad support from this community would be needed for such a change, and unfortunately that hasn't really panned out. Since this community is much smaller than Stack Overflow, it would probably take some time to get more than 10 people to vote or weigh in, and... in the meantime, the SO logo is returning to its normal state today. The moment has kinda passed.

I agree with Vincent - we should never stop celebrating! We were just unable to get our act together quickly enough to make this logo change be a thing. Oh well. Thanks anyway for all of your support :)

Answer (score 9):

I waited to voice my opinion because I didn't want to sway anything the community decided. Since we're past the point where it would matter I think there are important factors to consider.

I'm excited that the US seems to *finally* be moving in a more *realistic* direction.

**Congratulations!** to everyone this will directly effect. It's really fantastic that the country seems to be moving more quickly on this issue than we have in the past on other human rights issues.

That being posted, I would sort of echo the comment by @Jongware -- it's a slippery slope. **Support one political issue and you have to be open to supporting others, even if you disagree with them.**

It would be nice if the Federal Government outlawed the Confederate flag... Not that they will.. but if that decision were before the Court and the opponents won (keeping the confederate flag legal) would we be okay with the GD.SE logo getting that treatment to celebrate?

What if the federal government legalized recreational marijuana nationwide? Would a pot leaf GD.SE logo be okay?

Make no mistake, I am happy about the recent decisions the court has made (it's odd to have a Court that actually reflects the public more), but I don't really think open political statements belong on Stack sites. It sets a *very* bad precedence. In reality, I think it was out of place for SO to change their logo. The moment a site becomes political is the moment they start losing members. If that's not an issue, and the user base can use a bit of culling, then okay. But in general, I feel most web sites dealing with *technical* issues should be as autonomous as possible.

**Politics and religion just don't belong here.** In general, they only serve as divisive topics.

Just because *you* happen to believe in and support *this* issue (as I do) that doesn't mean you'll support *every* issue which may come up. Tolerance works both ways and it is often my observation that people are only really tolerant of issues they support.

Comment: Personally I think it was cool to see the logo changed on SO but I agree with you and a lot of other people for why the logo shouldn't be changed [Can Stack Overflow and Meta's logos be changed](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297859/can-stack-overflow-and-metas-logos-be-changed-temporarily-to-the-loveoverflow). I think both sides have valid points.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/MRlss

Comment: The slippery slope argument is a slippery slope in that we end up talking about slippery slopes instead of the fact that rarely is the slope all that slippery. :) While I agree people should be open to all political issues whether one agrees or disagrees, an equal rights declaration is a pretty unique and rare event and, IMHO, is hardly a slippery slope.

Comment: As for whether politics or religion belong in here, I agree on one level...on the other hand, what is graphic design if not persuasion? And what is politics and religion if not persuasion? :)

Comment: (Finally, tolerance doesn't work both ways much of the time. Often it's an issue of tolerance vs. intolerance. Not two-way tolerance, if that makes sense...)

Comment: On "slippery slope": one of the arguments *for* was that Joel, one of the SO founders (and thus GD:SE as well), was happy with the court decision for *personal reasons* and so he was happy to see it done. His decision; and so this needs reminding that SO is not a democratic website, *ultimately it is his company*. The This Be Slippery argument comes into play when (1) there is something to celebrate for 'a majority', but (2) Joel Does Not Particularly Like It.

Comment: I don't really feel comfortable calling this a political issue (not that I find anything wrong with politics, on the contrary). It's political for those not involved, but deeply personal for those that can finally get married. It's a human issue, in my opinion.

Comment: Not to argue @Yisela (but I'm gunna - bwahhaha!) ..... Suffrage and civil rights were political issues and also deeply personal to those it effected. It's human rights for certain, but also political :) **Most** political issues *are* deeply personal to anyone directly effected by them.

Comment: So who now redesigns the logo to celebrate for one day the EU Parliament decision to not restrict the freedom of panorama? That's at least remotely related to graphicdesign ...